# Faceted search engine with scoring

Tags: search, faceted-search

I'm looking for a search engine solution whereby there are attributes for each document which can be filtered against, but not absolutely - only scored.

doc1 has attributes a, b and c
doc2 has attributes b and c

if a user chooses attribute "a" only, it won't completely remove doc2, it'll just score doc1 higher...

Are there any search engines that can do something like that?

Comment: You may want to have a look on amazon cloud search in case you're looking for a SAAS solution

Answer (score 0):

You can build something like that with [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). You wouldn't use the built-in facets; instead, you would expose the attributes as links (perhaps in a facet-like way) and use them to add a scoring weight to that attribute, which can be sent as a parameter in a Solr query on the fly.